# How to parse location from Twitter Stream API using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, twitter

I have made a function in vb.net that parse JSON response from Twitter using the JSON.NET.
It's working great to parse the text, source and created_at. And I am actually using this code  in a program. But when I try to parse for example location I just get an empty string. I understand I maybe need an array. But why dont I need an array for text, source and created_at and how shall I declare the array, which values does it needs?

My code

```
  Private Sub ParseJson(ByVal Json As String)


    Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(Json)


    Dim tweet As String = o("text")
    Dim source As String = o("source")
    Dim created_at As String = o("created_at")


'See below, I get an empty string here

  Dim location As String = o("location")



End Sub
```

Comment: The database code doesn’t seem to be relevant to the question and yet it takes up most of the text. Please leave off irrelevant details such as this. It would be more interesting to see how the location information looks like, and how you attempt to parse it.

Comment: Konrad Rudolph : Sorry, I edited my code now.

Answer (score 1):

[According to an online discussion](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3755) there are quite varied ways of supplying the location information. A [sample query provided for testing purposes](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=TestPerson15&include_entities=true) for instance contains the following JSON fragment:

```
geo: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [
        47.73491243,
        -122.33668846
    ]
},
coordinates: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [
        -122.33668846,
        47.73491243
    ]
}
```

So instead of `location` you can read either `geo` or `coordinates` which is going to be a nested object. I don’t know which valid `type`s they have though.

The information is *also* supplied as a `place` which is an even more complex object:

```
place: {
    id: "ecb63eb9d9d83b31",
    url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/geo/id/ecb63eb9d9d83b31.json",
    place_type: "city",
    name: "Shoreline",
    full_name: "Shoreline, WA",
    country_code: "US",
    country: "United States",
    bounding_box: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [ … ]
    }
}
```

So in order to read the `place`, you could use the following:

```
String.Format("{0} ({1})", o("place")("full_name"), o("place")("country_code"))
```

which would return

```
Shoreline, WA (US)
```

It is my understanding that none of these properties are necessarily provided so that if you want to be robust you should test for the presence of all of them until you find one that yields the required information.